# Facebook linting url error

Tags: facebook

So right now my website is blocked by Facebook. I'm trying to find out why.

I went to this debugger by facebook: [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and it says that there's an error linting the url. I have no idea what this means.

How do I help facebook "lint" my url?

The full error is

"This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know."

"Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed - Error Linting URL An internal error occurred while linting the URL."

The URL in question is www.dreolo.com

Answer (score 0):

Try posting it on Facebook, there will be a popup where it says:

> If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

"let us know" is a link. Use that link to appeal.

Comment: there´s nothing else you can do, unfortunately. you can only wait.

Comment: It doent work as you have to keep submitting is for week most of the time no resolution